# How do I store an image into a variable in vue's composition API?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, image, vue.js

my code is below.

```
<template>
  <h1>Upload Form</h1>
  <div class="upload">
    <form @submit="uploadImage">
      <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Insert Name">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore, projectStorage } from '../firebase/config.js'

export default {
  setup() {
    const fileRef = ref(null);
    const image = ref(null);

    const onFileChange = (e) => {
      var file = e.target.file[0];
      image.value.createImage(file[0]);
      console.log(image)
    }

    // Uplopading image to server and get a reference for file on fileRef
    // const onFileChange = async(e) => {
    //   const file = e.target.files[0];
    //   const storageRef = projectStorage.ref('testupload/' + file.name);
    //   await storageRef.put(file)
    //   const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
    //   fileRef.value = url;
    //   console.log(fileRef.value)
    // }

    return { onFileChange}
  }

}
</script>
```

I have no idea how I can store an image into a Vue reference object in Vue3's composition API. I want to do this as I want to make it possible to upload my data to firebase after I click upload. May I know if there is anyway for me to store a image variable into a variable? Thanks!

Comment: First, `image` seems to be a `ref` of `null`. I don't see anywhere that you set it to anything. What is the `createImage()` function that you're calling on `image.value`? Second, you seem to be accessing the wrong property off of `e.target` -- it should be `files`, not `file`. (Though I see that in your commented out code you do reference it properly.) Why can't you just set `image.value` to your image file directly: `image.value=file`?

Comment: Hello, yeah I figured it out after a while of struggles, I initially tried what you were suggesting and couldnt find a solution. Upon googling, I found the solution in my code above and it did not work for me. Afterwards I got back and did something to similar to what you have suggested. Thanks for the help!